# host resolves the name but ping and browser do not

Tags: networking, macos, dns, ping, hostname

I observe the following *intermittent* behavior:

```
$ host foo.bar.com
foo.bar.com has address 172.17.13.217
foo.bar.com has address 10.33.111.101
$ ping -c 5 foo.bar.com
ping: cannot resolve foo.bar.com: Unknown host
$ ping -c 5 172.17.13.217
PING 172.17.13.217 (172.17.13.217): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.13.217: icmp_seq=0 ttl=248 time=10.557 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.13.217: icmp_seq=1 ttl=248 time=11.003 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.13.217: icmp_seq=2 ttl=248 time=13.226 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.13.217: icmp_seq=3 ttl=248 time=31.158 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.13.217: icmp_seq=4 ttl=248 time=10.573 ms

--- 172.17.13.217 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 10.557/15.303/31.158/7.989 ms
$ ping -c 5 10.33.111.101
PING 10.33.111.101 (10.33.111.101): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.33.111.101: icmp_seq=0 ttl=223 time=81.886 ms
64 bytes from 10.33.111.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=223 time=82.067 ms
64 bytes from 10.33.111.101: icmp_seq=2 ttl=223 time=82.340 ms
64 bytes from 10.33.111.101: icmp_seq=3 ttl=223 time=81.407 ms
64 bytes from 10.33.111.101: icmp_seq=4 ttl=223 time=81.368 ms

--- 10.33.111.101 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 81.368/81.814/82.340/0.377 ms
```

and the browser fails to find `foo.bar.com`.

And then a few minutes later everything is fine again - both chrome and `ping` find `foo.bar.com`.

What can be causing this behavior?
How come `host` can resolve `foo.bar.com` but `ping` and chrome cannot?
Is there anything that I can do - other than wait for a few minutes?

Comment: `host` looks up DNS. Other programs use other name resolution methods as configured in /etc/nsswitch.conf.

Comment: please describe your dns configuration. also it would help us to know if .bar is actually .local or something else.

Comment: @berndbausch: there is no `/etc/nsswitch.conf` on MacOS.

Comment: @FrankThomas: `.bar` is actually `.com`, see edit. I am not sure how to describe "dns configuration". Sorry.

Comment: You may want to add a tag "macos" or otherwise mention in the question or title that this is your OS.

Comment: @berndbausch: The behavior I observe is identical on the mac laptop and linux server.

Comment: Linux servers have the nsswitch, normally. In any case, I am pretty certain that a PC, be it a Mac, Windows or Linux PC uses mdns as one of the name resolution methods. `host` doesn't. foo.bar.com may not respond to mdns requests. I have similar problems with Windows PC in my home network - local name resolution of some devices is sometimes erratic. Tracing with a tool like Wireshark may confirm this.

Comment: For MacOS, have a look at the output of `scutil --dns`

Comment: To figure this out, you'll need to give us the exact macOS version, the output of `scutil --dns`, the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`, and the output of `dns-sd -G v4 foo.bar.com`. Please edit your Question to include that stuff. The `host` command uses its own built-in DNS resolver code instead of using macOS's resolver. `dns-sd -G v4…`shows what macOS's resolver is getting. Also, see if the problem has anything to do with whether you have a VPN connection up or not (the VPN settings could be causing the system to use the VPN server's preferred DNS servers).